# using search filter ajax for custom field type post

Tags: custom-post-types

I created some custom post type [by code not plugin] and I want to use search filter ajax for these post types.
here are my custom post types :

```
<?php
function add_custom_meta_box() {  
    add_meta_box(  
        'custom_meta_box',   
        'اطلاعات تور',   
        'show_custom_meta_box',   
        'post',   
        'normal',   
        'high');   
}  
add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'add_custom_meta_box');  
// Field Array  
    $prefix = 'dm_';  
    $custom_meta_fields = array(   

array(  
            'label'=> 'شروع قیمت از',  
            'desc'  => 'حداقل قیمت هر تور را به تومان وارد کنید',  
            'id'    => $prefix.'lowcost',  
            'type'  => 'text'  
        ),


        array(  
            'label'=> 'مبدا',  
            'desc'  => 'شهر مبدا تور را وارد کنید',  
            'id'    => $prefix.'mabda',  
            'type'  => 'text'  
        ),
        array(  
            'label'=> 'مقصد',  
            'desc'  => 'شهر مقصد را وارد کتید',  
            'id'    => $prefix.'maghsad',  
            'type'  => 'text'  
        ),



        array(  
            'label'=> 'اقامت',  
            'desc'  => 'تعداد شب های اقامت را مشخص کنید',  
            'id'    => $prefix.'eghamat',  
            'type'  => 'text'  
        ),


        array(  
            'label'=> 'هتل چند ستاره',  
            'desc'  => 'از بین عدد 1 تا 5 یک عدد را بنویسید',  
            'id'    => $prefix.'starrating',  
            'type'  => 'text'  
        ),


    );
    function show_custom_meta_box() {  
    global $custom_meta_fields, $post;   
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="custom_meta_box_nonce" value="'.wp_create_nonce(basename(__FILE__)).'" />';  
        echo '<table class="form-table">';  
        foreach ($custom_meta_fields as $field) {   
            $meta = get_post_meta($post->ID, $field['id'], true);  
            echo '<tr> 
                    <th><label for="'.$field['id'].'">'.$field['label'].'</label></th> 
                    <td>';  
                    switch($field['type']) {  
    case 'text':  
        echo '<input type="text" name="'.$field['id'].'" id="'.$field['id'].'" value="'.$meta.'" size="55" /> 
            <br /><span class="description">'.$field['desc'].'</span>';  
    break;
    // checkbox
case 'checkbox':
    echo '<input type="checkbox" name="'.$field['id'].'" id="'.$field['id'].'" ',$meta ? ' checked="checked"' : '','/>
        <label for="'.$field['id'].'">'.$field['desc'].'</label>';
break;  
                    } 
            echo '</td></tr>';  
        }  
        echo '</table>'; 
    }  
function save_custom_meta($post_id) {  
    global $custom_meta_fields;   
    if (!wp_verify_nonce($_POST['custom_meta_box_nonce'], basename(__FILE__)))  
        return $post_id;    
    if (defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE)  
        return $post_id;  
    if ('page' == $_POST['post_type']) {  
        if (!current_user_can('edit_page', $post_id))  
            return $post_id;  
        } elseif (!current_user_can('edit_post', $post_id)) {  
            return $post_id;  
    }  
    foreach ($custom_meta_fields as $field) {  
        $old = get_post_meta($post_id, $field['id'], true);  
        $new = $_POST[$field['id']];  
        if ($new && $new != $old) {  
            update_post_meta($post_id, $field['id'], $new);  
        } elseif ('' == $new && $old) {  
            delete_post_meta($post_id, $field['id'], $old);  
        }  
    }  
}  
add_action('save_post', 'save_custom_meta');        
?>
```

So I want use filter searching for these field post type ids : locost - eghamat - mabda - maghsad - starrating

Comment: Hello! Can you edit your question to fix the indenting/formatting of the code? It's a little difficult to process. Also, can you be more specific about what parts of the question you're unsure of or are missing the pieces of? What you want will require javascript

Comment: Hello. I want to make dropdown menu to use it for filter posts for example sort post by low cost [field type lowcost]

Comment: @m.javadKoushki Where do you want to do the filtering? On the admin posts list or for users on the front-end?

Comment: @AnttiKoskinen for users on frontend